# How to submit form using radio option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing my website in Safari. It works well in Safari, Firefox and Chrome. But in Explorer it's not working properly. Here I want to submit a form and direct to another page when a radio option is clicked. I have used `onChange="this.form.submit();` in the input. But it does not work in Explorer. Please suggest me a solution. I have tried query too. But that's also not working. I have attached the code below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    (function(document, window, $, undefined) {
        var form = $('#form-id');
        $('.radio-class').each(function(i, element) {
            var radio = $(element);
            radio.on('change', function() {
                // selected value
                var radioValue = $(this).val();
               form.submit();
            });
        });
    }(document, window, jQuery, undefined));

</script>

<body>
    <form action="go.php" method="post" id="form-id">
        <label for="radio-select"><input type="radio" name="radio-select" value="Mango" class="radio-class">Mango</label>
        <label for="radio-select"><input type="radio" name="radio-select" value="Apple" class="radio-class">Apple</label>
        <label for="radio-select"><input type="radio" name="radio-select" value="Pinaple" class="radio-class">Pinaple</label>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: If you want to add an event, use addEventListener or addListener (IE8)

Comment: thanks for your response. but can you explain bit more

Comment: FYI, unless you're doing something else that isn't in this code, you don't need to loop through `$('.radio-class')`, you can simply write `$('.radio-class').on('change',...` and it will work. jQuery do their own loop in the background so you're actually causing two loops to take place.

Comment: Another FYI, you can grab radio without a class by doing `$('input[type="radio"]')`. Works for checkboxes and such-like too.

Comment: @Neoares Not necessary. They are using jQuery to add an event listener and because they're using version 1 of jQuery, old versions of IE will be targetted too. jQuery will be doing those checks in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var form = $('#form-id');
        $('.radio-class').each(function(i, element){
            var radio = $(element);
            radio.on('change', function(){
                // selected value
                var radioValue = $(this).val();
                form.submit();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code inside $(document).ready() will be executed after the DOM is fully loaded. This way, the `.radio-class` elements will exist when the listener for the `change` event is added.

It's explained better [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

This is another example with a simplified loop:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = $('#form-id');
    $('.radio-class').on('change', function(){
        form.submit();
    });
});
```

And this is with the shorthand for $(document).ready()

```
$(function(){
    var form = $('#form-id');
    $('.radio-class').on('change', function(){
        form.submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: This code looks exactly the same as the original post. What have you changed?

Comment: thank you friends for you reply. i have sort out the problem by using a big code.        (function(document, window, $, undefined){
  
  //var form = $('#form-id');
  
  $('.radio-form').each(function(i, element){
    
    var radio = $(element).find('img');
    
    radio.on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
      // selected value
      var radioValue = $(this).val(),
      form = $(this).closest('.radio-form');
      console.log(form);
      form.submit();
     
    });
  
  });
  
}(document, window, jQuery, undefined));